# how to express a empty point?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI there! i created a array containing elements of type pcl::pointxyzrgb ,that is"pcl::pointxyzrgb point[160]"in a for loop,i want to check if the element is empty,i use "if (point[n]!=0)" .but when compiling,system warn that 0 is not the type of pcl::pointxyzrgb.so,i want to ask is there a way to express a empty point in pcl::pointxyzrgb format?how to initialize all the array elements with that empty point?thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149216/how-to-express-a-empty-point?/) by [keygeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/12986/keygeorge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A point cannot exactly be "empty" - it always has x,y,z,r,g,b members. You could create a new array without the points you don't want (the new array will be shorter). Or you could set x,y,z to NaN, and check for that in other parts of your code.

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2014-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [keygeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/12986/keygeorge/) on 2014-04-06**:
actually i was trying to extract the elements which are not empty from the array,in the for loop,i need to make sure the element is not empty so i can push_back it into another vector.so ,is there a way to initialize the array with empty point?

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-04-06**:
I believe its storing them in a vector, so no. Its a vector of points, so each element is a point (not something else like a null pointer).

**Comment by [keygeorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/12986/keygeorge/) on 2014-04-06**:
ok,thanks a lot.